# iframe on('load, function () {}) doesn't fire, why? .ready() fires

Tags: jquery, iframe

```
<iframe id="twitter-widget"><a></a></iframe>
```

```
$("#twitter-widget").on("load", function() {   
    console.log('Loaded');  //doesn't fire
});
```

On my page twitter twit is used. Loaded as iframe. Event doesn't fire on load, when I use ready instead - it fires. Can anyone please help?

Comment: If you write `$('#twitter-widget').ready(function() { console.log('Loaded'); });` then the `ready`event is not fired for the document of the iframe, but still for the document in which the iframe was loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers act differently on this. Some don't fire the 'load' event if the src is not set.
Try setting:

```
src="about:blank".
```